# Не добавляются новые записи в Core Data после обновления приложения

Tags: xcode, ios, coredata

В приложении после обновления не появляются новые записи Core Data. Получаю данные я так:

```
-(NSArray *) getObjects
{
    self.fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [self.fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [self.fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [self.fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [self.fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"provider"]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.resultArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    self.resultArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (![self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest error:nil]) {
        [self initData];
    }
    return self.resultArray;
}
```

Данные в Core Data записываю так:

```
Country *bosnherz = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Country" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
bosnherz.name = @"Bosnia and Herzegovina"];
```

Но если я допишу новые страны для новой версии, то после обновления они не показываются. При этом если приложение удалить и установить заново — все работает.
Если я верно понимаю, это происходит, потому что уже есть sql с данными и при запуске приложение использует его, а не создает новый. Отсюда вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы оно создавало новый после обновления?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас просто не срабатывает:

```
if (![self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:self.fetchRequest error:nil]) {
        [self initData];
}
```

потому что записи уже и так есть, нужно изменить проверку в новой версии, сделать ее не только по количеству записей, но и по какому-то еще признаку.

Еще вариант - удалять sqlite файл и persistentStores, могу скинуть код, если нужно, но в вашем случае лучше сделать правильную проверку.

Comment: сделал проверку на первый старт, если впервые — удаляю обьекты